# SetCursorPosition used in two threads simultaneously

Tags: c#, multithreading, console-application

I am currently writing a console game in C#. I am using two theads, both of which print something on the console with Console.SetCursorPosition(). But because the cursor is just one, the program sometimes swaps the places the text is printed and causes a mess. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Are you locking access to the console?

Comment: I really am tempted to down vote based on your user name. But I won't.

Answer (score 3):

sounds like you need a lock around the setposition and the write

```
lock(x)
{
 Console.SetCursorPosition()
 Console.Write();
}
```

where x is an object allocated for this purpose. It must be shared amongst all the threads

Comment: Exactly what I was going to answer with. Kudo's and +1 to you.